# jQuery use one of two events if either work

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This works in Chrome but Firefox doesn't seem to like it. I want to be able to use either `mousedown` or `pointerdown`, not both at the same time. Using a ',' comma works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.element').on('mousedown, pointerdown', function(){
    // Without comma it fires twice
});
```

Is `pointerdown` not supported in Firefox?

Comment: There should be no comma. You'll have to keep track of the handler firing somehow, or else use `.stopImmediatePropagation()` with the event parameter (which is missing from your code).

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is: https://caniuse.com/#search=pointerdown

Comment: It works in Chrome because Chrome supports "pointerdown" and the event "mousedown," (with that trailing comma) doesn't exist.

Comment: @Albzi wasn't aware of that site! Thanks!